# Error: Missing query string MariaDB NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mariadb

I have this error every time I try to run a query to DB:

```
Error: Missing query string
```

I don't understand what could be wrong with my code, the query is correct I have tested it:

```
function getChannelCTSize(octopusMac, channelID, adcTicks, callback){
    var queryString = "SELECT Channels.CT_size FROM Channels INNER JOIN Octopus ON Octopus.Id=Channels.Octopus_Id WHERE Octopus.Mac = ? AND Channels.Channel_Id = ?";
    var filter = [octopusMac, channelID];

    var query = mariaDB.query({
        sql: queryString
    }, filter );

    query.on('error', function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.code);
            return
        }
    })
        .on('result', function(row) {
            callback(result[0].CT_size, channelID, octopusMac, adcTicks);
        })
        .on('end', function() {
            mariaDB.release();
        });
}
```

Comment: which node package are you using for mariadb?

Comment: I am using mariasql

Comment: you mean this package [node-mariasql](https://github.com/mscdex/node-mariasql)

Comment: yes sorry my bad

Comment: what should the `filter` do?
Just return entries with `octopusMac` like the value you gave to the method?

Comment: filter is used in the querry to replace the '?' with an actual value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137946/discussion-between-tobias-lins-and-remi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `query` function of `mariasql` should be invoked with a string as first argument (the query) instead of an object)

It should look like:

```
var queryString = "SELECT Channels.CT_size FROM Channels INNER JOIN Octopus ON Octopus.Id=Channels.Octopus_Id WHERE Octopus.Mac = :octopusMac AND Channels.Channel_Id = :channelID";

var query = mariaDB.query(queryString, { octopusMac, channelID }, function(err, rows) {
  if (err)
    console.log(err.code);

  callback(rows[0].CT_size, channelID, octopusMac, adcTicks);
})
```

Comment: I have tried this but the code never returns any err

Comment: The second argument in your example has a typo on syntax. It should be an array. An object works too if you prepare the statement with `:octopusMac` or whatever name in there.